# Excel VBA loop through combobox with select case statements

Tags: excel, vba, loops, switch-statement

I have a worksheet with 6 activex comboboxes.

Combobox1 has 21 choiches.
Combobox2 is dependent on Combobox1, number of choices vary.

Combobox3 has 2 choices.
Combbox4 is dependent on Combobox3 and has 21 choices.

Combobox5 has 21 choiches.
Combobox6 is dependent on Combobox5, number of choices vary.

I would like to loop through combobox1 - value1 and combobox2 - value1.

Then I would like to loop through combobox3 - value 1 and combobox4 - value1.

I would like to loop through combobox5 - value1 and combobox6 - value1.

I am using vlookup to based on the linked cells of the different comboboxes. The code I have at the moment only loops through the cell values of combobox1 and combobox2. I would like to physically change the value in the combobox, from value1 to lastvalue.

Which would be Combobox1 - value1, combobox2 value1 to last value, combobox3 first value, combobox4 - value1, combobox 5, value1 and finally combobox6 - value1 to last value.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim cb As ComboBox

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet

    For Each shp In Ws.Shapes
        With shp
            Select Case .Type
                Case msoFormControl
                    If .FormControlType = xlDropDown Then
                        If .ControlFormat.Value = 0 Then
                            MsgBox .Name & " = "
                        Else
                            MsgBox .Name & " = " & .ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.Value)
                        End If
                    End If
                Case msoOLEControlObject
                    If .OLEFormat.progID = "Forms.ComboBox.1" Then
                        Set cb = .OLEFormat.Object.Object
                        MsgBox cb.Name & " = " & cb.Value
                    End If
            End Select
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

The code above gives me the values of my 6 activex comboboxes.

```
 Sub try()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Count = 0

    For Each OleObj In Ws.OLEObjects
        If OleObj.OLEType = xlOLEControl Then
            If TypeName(OleObj.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
                Count = Count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next OleObj

    MsgBox "Number of ComboBoxes :" & Count

    End Sub
```

This code counts the amount of comboboxes in a sheet! Maybe it can be adapted to increment each combobox?

I am thinking about something like this:

```
Sub Test()

Select Case Me.Form
    Case "Stockholms län"
        Me.Kommun1.RowSource = "Stockholms_län"
        ' Code for each loop where combobox1 is "Stockholm län" and Combobox2  
        ' is a named range.
    Case "Skåne län"
        Me.Kommun1.RowSource = "Skåne_län"
        ' Code for each loop where combobox1 is "Skåne län" and Combobox2 is 
        ' a named range.


End Select
End sub
```

I can manually set the values of combobox1 and combobox2.

```
Sub WantToLoop()
    Dim län1 As String
    Dim kommun1 As String

    Dim län2 As String
    Dim kommun2 As String

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").län1 = "Skåne län"
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").kommun1 = "Bjuv"

End Sub
```

The code above kind of works but I can't do select cases for several hundred of choices. How can I loop this?

I am getting closer but now I am setting the value of the combobox. I want to access the value of the combobox.

```
Sub try()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To 2
   Sheets("Test").Shapes("Län" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object = "item" & i
   Sheets("Test").Shapes("Kommun" & i).OLEFormat.Object.Object = "item" & i

Next

End sub

Sub IterateComboBox()
Dim i As Long
  With Sheets("Jämföra").Län1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
    'Debug.Print .List(i)
    .Value = .List(i)
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

This code does what I want. How can I turn this into a select case?

```
Sub Try2()
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Sheets("Test").Län1.ListIndex = 0

For l = 0 To 25
Sheets("Test").Kommun1.ListIndex = l

Sheets("Test").Län2.ListIndex = 0

For n = 0 To 25
Sheets("Test").Kommun2.ListIndex = n

Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Sheets("Score").Select

Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Län1, Kommun1 OK
Cells(LR, "A").Value = Sheets("Test").Range("G5").Value
Cells(LR, "B").Value = Sheets("Test").Range("G6").Value
Next
Next
End Sub
```

This code loops through combobox1 value1, combobox2 all values, combobox3 value1 and combobox4 all values. How can I turn this into a case?

Or how do I turn this into a function where I can pass the values of Län1, Kommun1, Län2 and Kommun2 into the function??